# Как получить новый URL, при запросе старого через GET?

Tags: javascript

Есть URL, который запрашиваю через GET на `javascript`. После этого адрес должен изменится немного. Как мне получить свежий адрес, возможно ли это?

Например было URL.ru/1 -> стало URL.RU/2 и нам необходимо его получить.

Вроде существует `HISTORY API`. Но как правильно воспользоваться - не знаю.

Comment: А 302 редирект не подойдет?

Comment: Через какой класс запрашиваешь?  location.href не подходит?

Comment: @nick_n_a Через кросс доменные запросы GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиском пытались пользоваться?

С `history api` все очень просто:

```
window.history.pushState(data, title [, url]): Добавляет элемент истории.
window.history.replaceState(data, title [, url]): Обновляет текущий элемент истории
```

Более детально например по ПЕРВОЙ статье в поиске – https://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/

Учитесь, пожалуйста, пользоваться поиском, иначе вам будет очень трудно в ИТ.

### UPD

Если вы имеете ввиду, что старый адрес не доступен, а владельцы сайте его перенесли, то при использовании редиректа для вас это будет прозрачно, а если нет, то никак.

Comment: Разъясните некоторый моменты,пожалуйста.То есть мы берём, добавляем делаем наш урл,делаем кросс доменный запрос и обновляем элемент?

Comment: @Maksym смотря что вам нужно. Если вы хотите имитировать переход по ссылке, в момент загрузки новой страницы через AJAX запрос вам нужно изменить урл через `window.location.hash` и добавить новый урл в историю через `window.history.pushState()`

Comment: Нет ,как раз есть два сайта.Мой и чужой. Так вот,я запрашиваю урл чужого сайта со своего JSом при этом оставляя юзера на своем. А урл чужого сайта при переходе меняется на уникальный.Как этот уникальный урл получить?

Comment: @Maksym что значит меняется? Дайте пример ссылки

Comment: Есть идея. Взять IFRAME и загрузить страницу через него.А потом свежий урл взять в истории после переадресаций или так далее?

Comment: Если вы через jQuery.AJAX делаете, то смотрите ответ сервера, там должен быть новый урл

Comment: Вот например есть `oauth.vk.com/redirect_uri=http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html` .Нас перекинет на `http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html` с уникальным hash.Это ж можно увидеть через ответ сервера?